# Push notification handling if app is not open

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

wen my app receives notification when its not open (not running in background) i read somewhere that i can handle/access notifications via :

```
NSDictionary *tmpDic = [launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
//if tmpDic is not nil, then your app is launched due to an APNs push, therefore check this NSDictionary for further information
if (tmpDic != nil) {
    NSLog(@" - launch options dict has something ");
    NSLog(@" - badge number is %@ ", [[tmpDic objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"]);
    NSLog(@" - ");
}
```

but thats only working when one notification is sent. What if the User received more than one? how could i handle them ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

To handle multiple notifications in a row you could store the data for each and then when the app opens again display some kind of interface for the user to view each one.

Comment: did receive push notification method is not being called when the app is not even running . how to capture and save notifications to load them later on when the app is not running ?